A confusion related to concrete category in Hungerford Book
I am reading the T.W. Hungerford's Algebra book. In Chapter 1, section 7, categories: Products, coproducts, and free objects are included. I am the first learner of Category Theory. Here an example of the category was given in the following way:

A (multiplicative) group $G$can be considered as a category with one object, $G$. Let $hom(G,G) $ be the set of elements of $G$. The composition of morphism $a,b$ is simply the composition $ab$ given by the binary operation in $G$.

That's fine for me. But, in the definition of the Concrete category (Definition 7.6) He uses this example to construct a non-example of the Concrete Category in the following way:

If the function $\sigma$ assigns to the group $G$ the usual underlying set $G$, then the category is not a concrete category (since morphisms are not functions on the set $G$).

I have difficulty understanding the line: "since morphisms are not functions on the set $G$". It may be a very elementary thing but why are morphisms not functions on the set, please help me to understand it. Thank you beforehand!!!


(since morphisms are not functions on the set $G$)

This is a poor way to phrase it. Whether something is or isn't a function on $G$ is not an invariant statement under isomorphism, and thus violates the principle of equivalence. In fact there is a natural way to see an element $g : G$ as a function on $G$: just take the left (or right) multiplication action $x \mapsto g \cdot x : G \to G$.
Indeed the delooping category of a group $G$ can be made into a concrete category that way, since the functor to $\mathbf{Set}$ thus obtained is faithful.
If the author is wrong about something so fundamental, I'd recommend against learning category theory from that book. I suggest a more recent reference like Category theory in context by Emily Riehl, which defines concrete categories correctly.

I was about to give the same suggestion; every small category is concrete.

The author clearly meant that the group elements are not equal to functions.

@MartinBrandenburg but they might be, depending on how you encode functions and how the group's underlying set is defined. This is not a sensible question to ask, and in sensible foundations (namely, anything but material set theory) it's not something you can ask. Category theory should not inherit nonsense from its foundations.

Of course I agree. I just wanted to clarify the author's intent.
